# How to input a value to an existed csv file?

Tags: python, csv

So i've tried to find solutions on youtube but all of them just write a new file.

How to input a value to an existed csv file? Can I do that in Python (IDLE)?

for example this is my csv file:

[Image for the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xFOR.png)

So what I want to do is to input a DATE & ID & FEEDBACK in python then the they will be written automatically in excel.

[This is the expected output in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9fkO.png)

```
import csv

with open('feedback.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    next(csv_writer)
    for line in csv_file:
        csv_writer.writerow() #How to input date,id,and feedback from user?
#the expected output is in the 2nd image
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Also repeat your tutorials on getting user input and writing to a CSV file; everything you need is contained in those; we expect to see an honest coding attempt, rather than asking us to write it for you.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Have you done any research on how to append to a file?

Comment: @AMC My issue has been solved by someone who answered this question down there. Just by giving me those simple examples, I can elaborate. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before:  [image: Before] 
After: [image: After]

```py
import csv

some_feedback = ['3/3/2000', 'AAAAA', 'Great'] 
more_feedback = [['4/4/2000', 'BBBBB', 'Good'], ['5/5/2000', 'CCCCC', 'Great']]

with open('feedback.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    csv_writer.writerow(some_feedback)

    csv_writer.writerows(more_feedback)
```

Please note the `'a'` mode given to the file opener. This will ensure that any rows written are appended to the existing ones. See [mode in which a file is opened](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open).

Also, see the [csv module examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#examples).